# sed removes one string in one file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to remove one string in one file by using:

```
sed -i -e '/example/' test.txt
```

But I've got the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: missing command
```

What is it missing and why?

Thanks!

Comment: the syntax is `sed 's/find/replace/' file`.

Comment: Hi fedorqui, thanks! I would like to remove the string `/example/` but this is not working: `sed 's/example//' test.txt` Any suggestion?

Comment: Is `/example/` a real string here or some pattern you are giving? Please [edit] your question giving a [mcve].

Comment: Hi there, it seems to work but as I open the file to check the changes, the string is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/example/` is an **address** which tells sed where to run commands - on a line containing the string `example`. You didn't specify any commands.

This is a commnand that replaces the string `example` with an empty string:

```
's/example//'
```

Comment: Shouldn't those backticks be single-quotes? e.g: `'s/example//'`

Comment: @user3439894: Of course. I'm not sure why I did that.

Comment: I've got it! saving to a file with the same name was missing `sed 's/sample//' sample.txt > sample.txt` Many thanks guys! you rock!

Comment: @Chüngel: Saving to the same file might not work, as it can overwrite the file before you can read from it. Use a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sed '/example/d' test.txt
```

Explanation as suggested by @Nathan Tuggy

sed will search for the given string and will 'D'elete it

```
user@host:~$ cat test.txt 
one
two
three
user@host:~$ sed '/two/d' test.txt 
one
three
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: user@host:~$ cat test.txt 
one
two
three
user@host:~$ sed '/two/d' test.txt 
one
three